# libreoffice won't launch

Tags: libreoffice

I've been happily using LibreOffice 6.4 this morning. I've not changed anything nor installed or deleted any software or changed any settings.

Now it won't run. I click the icon and the app name appears in the top bar but with a spinning circle that then disappears. I've rebooted, shutdown etc.

Googling it says remove ~/.config/libreoffice and try again, but this folder does not exist.

I'm on 18.04 and help would be appreciated. I can only assume something has corrupted somewhere but I'm not entirely sure how to find out. I think I installed it via the Ubuntu software centre but not entirely certain. There is a ~/snap/libreoffice folder.

Thanks

Update #1

Running from terminal (the app does launch but it looks different)

```
roger@roger-ubuntu:~$ soffice
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Please ensure that a JVM and the package libreoffice-java-common
is installed.
If it is already installed then try removing ~/.libreoffice/3/user/config/javasettings_Linux_*.xml
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
```

Comment: Remove the snap version, install the regular default version instead (it might be installed already, so just removing the snap version may allow you to run the regular version).

Comment: Thank you. Simplenote and Skype also now refuse to launch. I don't understand this? what can suddenly change to take an app out of action? It would make sense after a system upgrade but that's not the case here. Very frustrating.

Comment: And what is the 'regular' version please? apt? Ubuntu Software app? downloaded deb package?

Comment: The one that comes with the default installation, or which you can install using 'sudo apt get install libreoffice' or by selecting the correct entry in the Software center (there is a snap version and a regular version there)

Comment: Thanks. I'm fairly sure I installed it via Software Centre - it's in there and states installed. I've re-installed it that way and it works, but there's still a  ~/snap/libreoffice folder so I'm a little confused!

Comment: That means you installed the Snap at one time. This user config folder is never automatically deleted, so then it would be normal you still see it. Try opening LO from the command line (terminal). Output in the command line might give a clue on what is wrong. The name of the executable is still "soffice" (from the former Star Office).

Comment: I can run it from the terminal but get the error I've put in my edited post and it looks different to the one I've re-installed from the Software Centre. Could I have two versions installed?

Comment: Snap and regular version.

Comment: OK thank you. Looks like I've got myself in a kerfuffle... I'll have to investigate doing a clean up. Cheers for your help.